# Javascript e componentes deixam de responder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, iis

Estou tendo alguns problemas com tempos de sessão (deduzo que seja esse o problema) na minha aplicação.

O meu cliente diz que por vezes a aplicação não funciona, nomeadamente Javascript's e componentes que fazem parte da aplicação (DevExpress). Ao fazer análise deste problema deduzi que o utilizador fica muito tempo "parado" na mesma página (faz uma pausa ou algo do género), e depois quando regressa, algumas acções que são feitas por JavaScript ou outro componentes não funcionam, tendo de se mudar de página ou fazer *refresh* para voltar a trabalhar... Daí deduzir que seja problemas de *Session Timeout*.

Não sei se estou certo ou não, mas o que tentei fazer foi:

No meu *Web.config* colocar:

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="1"></sessionState>
    ...
</system.web>
```

E no IIS fui às *Gerir Web Site > Definições Avançadas* e aumentei o *Limite de Tempo de Ligação*

Coloquei tempos de sessão pequenos para conseguir verificar se esta situação acontecia, mas até agora nada...

Comment: Amigo você sabia que se a aplicação ficar parada por 20 ou mais minutos que o IIS mata seu sistema. Pode ser isto que esteja ocorrendo.

Comment: A minha questão é se não dá para aumentar esse tempo @Marconi

Comment: Olhe se isto pode te ajudar.
http://forums.asp.net/t/1950241.aspx?ASP+NET+MVC+website+goes+to+sleep+How+to+nake+it+always+awake+

Comment: Pelo que vi é o que estou a fazer

Comment: ajudou em algo?

Comment: Sinceramente não. Diz-me para mudar o Timeout no IIS e o tempo no web.config, coisas que já estou a tentar fazer :/